# Комментарий к тексту.

Tags: егэ

Пытаюсь несколько дней найти литературный аргумент по данному тексту.Безуспешно....
Автор поднимает проблему будущего письменности и проблему информационного взрыва.Моя ученица написала сочинение по проблеме письменности,помочь ей с аргументами литературными у меня не получается...Если по второй проблеме я нашла аргументы,то по первой не могу.Помогите,пожалуйста!
Исходный текст для сочинения.
(1)Количество «универсальных» сим­во­лов с каж­дым годом растёт, ибо по­яв­ля­ют­ся новые на­уч­ные дисциплины, со­вер­шен­ству­ют­ся и вво­дят свою спе­ци­аль­ную символику такие науки, как биология, психология, лингвистика. (2)Не озна­ча­ет ли это, что наше пись­мо возвращается вспять, к пиктографии, то есть ри­су­ноч­но­му письму?

(3)В какой-то мере — да. (4)Но в то же самое время, со­зда­вая новые символы-идеограммы, че­ло­ве­че­ство не от­ка­зы­ва­ет­ся и от до­сти­же­ний тысячелетий — от фо­не­ти­че­ско­го письма. (5)Таким образом, наша пись­мен­ность становится смешанной, «буквенно-идеографической». (6)Например, тек­сты научных ста­тей по ма­те­ма­ти­ке или ядер­ной физике на­пи­са­ны именно таким буквенно-идеографическим письмом. (7)Преимущество его по срав­не­нию с ал­фа­ви­том очевидно. (8)Во-первых, идео­грам­мы понятны не­за­ви­си­мо от языка (химические формулы, ма­те­ма­ти­че­ские символы), во-вторых, они не толь­ко сокращают запись, но и по­мо­га­ют научному мыш­ле­нию (прогресс ма­те­ма­ти­ки обязан глав­ным образом вве­де­нию специальной символики, со­зда­нию «языка математики»). (9)А в-третьих, такая сим­во­ли­ка становится по­нят­ной не толь­ко любому человеку, но и компьютерам.

(10)«Информационный взрыв» — так на­зы­ва­ют невероятно боль­шое количество информации, ко­то­рое лавинообразно воз­рас­та­ет с каж­дым годом. (11)Со вре­ме­ни Гуттенберга до наших дней вышло более 35 мил­ли­о­нов книг, и цифра эта явно заниженная, так как огром­ное количество спе­ци­аль­ных изданий не по­сту­па­ет на книж­ный рынок.

(12)Не удивительно, что учёные не в со­сто­я­нии прочесть всю вы­хо­дя­щую литературу даже по их узкой специальности. (13)Вот по­че­му в на­сто­я­щее время един­ствен­ное спасение от этого по­то­ка информации, ко­то­рый к тому же еже­год­но возрастает, — со­зда­ние информационно-логических машин, по­стро­ен­ных на ос­но­ве электронно-вычислительной техники.

(14)С по­мо­щью «машинной письменности» можно, минуя пе­ре­вод с языка на язык, за­пи­сы­вать в элек­трон­ной памяти всю не­об­хо­ди­мую информацию. (15)Система уни­вер­саль­ной символики, меж­ду­на­род­ные знаки науки с каж­дым годом совершенствуются, но рань­ше это происходило, так сказать, стихийно, без уча­стия специалистов. (16)И толь­ко в по­след­ние годы XX века стало ясно, что не по­след­нее слово при­над­ле­жит здесь лингвистам, ко­то­рые занимаются не толь­ко примитивной идео­гра­фи­ей первобытных племён, но и со­вре­мен­ной научной идеографией.

(17)«Машинная письменность», она же «универсальный код науки», она же и «всемирное письмо», будет создана. (18)Это будет идеография, по­нят­ная любому че­ло­ве­ку и вы­чис­ли­тель­ной машине. (19)Но из этого вовсе не следует, что ис­чез­нет фонетическое, бук­вен­ное письмо. (20)Ведь живая раз­го­вор­ная речь со­хра­нит­ся и будет раз­ви­вать­ся и совершенствоваться, по-прежнему будут тво­рить на своём род­ном языке поэты и прозаики. (21)3начит, оста­нет­ся и алфавит — сред­ство записи жи­во­го слова. (22)Правда, и здесь тех­ни­ка может вне­сти существенные коррективы: ав­то­ры сейчас за­пи­сы­ва­ют свои про­из­ве­де­ния на диктофоны, любой роман может быть «наговорён», су­ще­ству­ет уже мно­же­ство электронных библиотек, со­сто­я­щих из «звуковых книг». (23)Однако зву­ча­щее слово может быть по­да­но в раз­лич­ных интерпретациях (вспомните чте­ние стихов в ис­пол­не­нии самих ав­то­ров и ма­сте­ров художественного чтения). (24)Поэтому и алфавит, и книга, вероятно, будут жить века, толь­ко сфера их упо­треб­ле­ния значительно сузится. (25)Научная, специальная, тех­ни­че­ская литература будет за­пи­сы­вать­ся «средствами ма­шин­ной письменности», а художественная — сред­ства­ми привычного тра­ди­ци­он­но­го письма. (26)В этом смыс­ле буквы умрут толь­ко вместе с живым че­ло­ве­че­ским словом.
(По А. Кондратову*)

*Александр Ми­хай­ло­вич Кондратов (1937-1993) — рос­сий­ский лингвист, биолог, жур­на­лист и поэт.

Comment: Вам нужны именно "литературные аргументы"?
Признаться, не совсем понимаю, что это такое применительно к данным тезисам. Набор художественных текстов? Академические исследования? Эссе? Или просто поговорить?    
  
С другой стороны, сами по себе эти тезисы мне кажутся во многом весьма сомнительны, но хаводить критический разговор не буду без Вашего явно выраженного на то пожелания.

Comment: Спасибо,что откликнулись! Мне необходим аргумент из читательского опыта,я имею в виду К4 из части С Егэ.

Comment: Я по ЕГЭ специалист никакой. 
Это к Людмиле.

Answer (score 1):

1.«История ума представляет две главные эпохи, — говорил русский историк Николай Михайлович Карамзин, — изобретение букв и типографии: все другие были их следствием. Чтение и письмо открывает человеку новый мир» - высказывание подтверждает мысль о том, что письменность никогда не исчезнет, книга будет жить всегда если не в печатном, то в электронном виде, на каких угодно носителях, которые ещё придумает человечество.

2.Что будет с человечеством без письменности, показал нам фантаст Р.Брэдбери в книге "451 градус по Фаренгейту" :уничтожены книги-погибла человеческая нравственность. Люди заучивали книги наизусть, чтобы сохранить их для будущего человечества, потому что иначе погибнет цивилизация, исчезнет вся информация о мире.

3.Есть замечательная книга Н. Петровича " Люди и биты. Информационный взрыв: 
что он несет"  http://sbiblio.com/biblio/archive/nikolay_ludi/00.aspx

Автор приходит к логически обоснованному выводу – проблема «ЧЕЛОВЕК – ИНФОРМАЦИЯ», несмотря на стремительный рост потока информации, может быть решена при некоторых условиях. Главными из них являются:
•   содружество человека и быстродействующих ЭВМ по обработке, хранению и поиску информации;
•   широкое использование быстродействующих каналов связи с выходными экранами, подключаемых к информационным ЭВМ, для запроса и просмотра на рабочем месте или даже дома интересующих сведений;
•   достойное отношение к ценнейшему информационному ресурсу, новая тактика работы с ним, бережное отношение человека как к своему, так и чужому времени.

Comment: Людмила,Вам огромная благодарность! Вы меня выручили!